# Sourcing scripts in [r] shows warnings since 2.15.1

Tags: r, rstudio

I installed R (2.15.1) and RStudio (0.96.316) on a new mac. Now everytime I source an R-script I get the following warning message. No matter what the script looks like. In the next case I just used one cat('Hello World) argument.

```
> source('~/Documents/R-Files/skript.r')
Hello World

Warnmeldung:
In eval.with.vis(ei, envir) :
  .Internal(eval.with.vis) should not be used and will be removed soon
```

I get always the same amount of warnings as lines in my code.
Having a script with four lines of input produces four warnings:

```
> source('~/Documents/R-Files/skript.r')
a Hello World
b Hello World
c Hello World
d Hello World

Warnmeldungen:
1: In eval.with.vis(ei, envir) :
  .Internal(eval.with.vis) should not be used and will be removed soon
2: In eval.with.vis(ei, envir) :
  .Internal(eval.with.vis) should not be used and will be removed soon
3: In eval.with.vis(ei, envir) :
  .Internal(eval.with.vis) should not be used and will be removed soon
4: In eval.with.vis(ei, envir) :
  .Internal(eval.with.vis) should not be used and will be removed soon
```

However, R-scripts work fine besides the warning messages.

I found the following information on [R News](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html):

> - source() now uses withVisible() rather than .Internal(eval.with.vis). This sometimes alters tracebacks slightly.

I think this is the reason for my problem, but I don't know the solution.
How can I disable or avoid the warning?

Comment: I think most of us have no crystal ball at home - what's the code in your script?

Comment: Have you tried this in standalone `R --vanilla` to ensure that it's (a) not an Rstudio issue and (b) not due to some weird leftover `.RData` file?

Comment: I had the problem with any script. So I just used a "cat('Hello World')" to show you my problem.
Finally it was an issue with an .RData file.

Comment: You may need to wait a little while, but you should post the answer to your own question and how you discovered it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debugging Example:  "eval.with.vis" warning (this case XML library, your case, any library)

On my Mac after a 2.15.1 upgrade, I found the problem to be in the XML library by using binary search.

When I commented out this statement:  library("XML")   the warnings went away.

I traced this to the fact I was using a binary XML library from CRAN.

When I re-installed the library from the source (by using the R gui App menu selection "Packages and Data->Package Installer" and the using the left top drop down menu and selecting "CRAN (Sources)"), the R app rebuilt the library from source.

After this, the warnings were not longer present.

I suggest that you too determine which one of your libraries is using the "eval.with.vis" deprecated code, and then try re-compiling it from the source to make sure you have the latest version.  If this doesn't work, you can change the source code itself to use the current version "withVisible".

I wasted three hours tracing this bug down.

If anyone knows of an automated way to re-install all the libraries, and then to manually find the ones that are causing the warnings, and then to semi-automatically re-install from source the offending libraries, that would be great.

Good luck all!

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem, and the same successful solution (reinstalling the package) with library("foreign") under the partial session info below.

- R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
- Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)
- RStudio 0.97.248

Thanks for this solution.